# JDBC insert query does not insert record in database

Tags: java, database

I have a little problem. My database doesn't work and I don't know why.. There's no error. Everything looks fine, im typing values and my web app says "saved into database" it's not true. Database is empty.
Here's my code:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/CarRental";
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static Statement stmt = null;

    public void createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,"GioRgio","12345");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addClient(Klienci klienci) {

        String query = "INSERT INTO KLIENCI"
                + "(ID, IMIE, NAZWISKO, ADRES, TELEFON, MAIL)"
                + " VALUES (" + klienci.getId_klienta() + ",'" + klienci.getImie() + "','" 
                + klienci.getNazwisko() + "'," + klienci.getAdres()+"',"+klienci.getTelefon()+"',"+klienci.getMail() + ")"; 

        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
            sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + ";shutdown=true");
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I carefully checked your code but I do not really see a problem. After revisiting an example here https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/derby_app.html I would at least suggest to try replace executeUpdate() with execute() maybe this solves the problem or shows more

Comment: Is `autoCommit` turned on?  You may need to commit the changes

Comment: In `closeConnection()` you `catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {}` but do not log anything.  Could that be hiding your problem?

Comment: I would also suggest using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to prevent the possibility of dangling resources

Comment: The last thing I have in mind is the connection string, worth a shot to pack your credentials directly into the URL like shown in the example I linked above, maybe the current implementation is hiding something!

Comment: @thex Check again, the insert statement is being incorrectly escaped, in at least one place.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen out of curiosity which literal I don't see it

Comment: Most fields seem to have problems actually.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see it, you are right the ' is missing at multiple places, interesting that doesn't throw an exception or some sort of error, in that case I would have expected that some columns would simple be empty / null

Comment: That assumes the single quotes are balanced (i.e. there is an even number of them).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tbh I didn't count them :P

Answer (score 2):

The immediate cause of the problem seems to be an incorrectly escaped literal in the `INSERT` statement (the address).  We *could* try to fix that, but it would be much better to use a prepared statement, which handles the escaping itself.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO KLIENCI (ID, IMIE, NAZWISKO, ADRES, TELEFON, MAIL) ";
sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,)";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, klienci.getId_klienta());
ps.setString(2, klienci.getImie());
ps.setString(3, klienci.getNazwisko());
ps.setString(4, klienci.getAdres());
ps.setString(5, klienci.getTelefon());
ps.setString(6, klienci.getEmail());

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @Catttiee Yes it does. See my [example app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753401/642706) using the kind of code shown here.

Comment: @Catttiee Don't we all. ;-)  Embedding SQL within another programming language is a hassle, an inelegant mess. The [Raw Strings Literal](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/326) feature coming in Java 12 or 13 should help.

Comment: So i got this. I don't have any errors, but still my database doesn't work.. I worked before on my code in another project and everything was fine. My brain will explode xd

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53753169/642706) is correct about mistyping your SQL text and about the advice to use a prepared statement.

## Example app

In support of his Answer, here is a complete example app. Using [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) rather than [Derby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby).

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.UUID;

public class CustomerDbEx {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        CustomerDbEx app = new CustomerDbEx();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {

        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:customer_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ) ; // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE customer_ ( \n" +
                    "  id_ UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                    "  given_name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                    "  surname_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                    "  address_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                    "  phone_ VARCHAR NOT NULL , \n" +
                    "  email_ VARCHAR NOT NULL \n" +
                    ");";
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert rows.
            sql = "INSERT INTO customer_ ( id_ , given_name_ , surname_ , address_ , phone_ , email_ ) \n";
            sql += "VALUES ( ? , ? , ? ,  ? , ? , ?  ) \n";
            sql += ";";
            try (
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            ) {
//                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , customer.getId() );
//                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , customer.getGivenName() );
//                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , customer.getSurname() );
//                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , customer.getAddress() );
//                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , customer.getPhone() );
//                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , customer.getEmail() );
//                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , UUID.fromString( "ddbf2754-f9aa-4ec3-98e9-b03da4aa83d1" ) );
                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , "Wendy" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , "Melvoin" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 4 , "101 Main ST" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 5 , "(525) 555-1911" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 6 , "wendy@example.com" );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                preparedStatement.setObject( 1 , UUID.fromString( "5851c90a-f1cb-4706-a329-c54890e4d190" ) );
                preparedStatement.setString( 2 , "Lisa" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 3 , "Coleman" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 4 , "787 Dream ST" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 5 , "(525) 555-7824" );
                preparedStatement.setString( 6 , "lisa@example.com" );
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


            }

            // Query all.
            sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_ ;";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    UUID id = rs.getObject( "id_" , UUID.class );
                    String givenName = rs.getString( "given_name_" );
                    String surname = rs.getString( "surname_" );
                    String address = rs.getString( "address_" );
                    String phone = rs.getString( "phone_" );
                    String email = rs.getString( "email_" );

                    System.out.println( "Customer: " + id + " | " + givenName + " | " + surname + " | " + address + " | " + phone + " | " + email );

                    // Instantiate a `Customer` object for this data.
//                    Customer c = new Customer( id , givenName , surname , address , phone , email );
                }
            }
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When run.

> Customer: ddbf2754-f9aa-4ec3-98e9-b03da4aa83d1 | Wendy | Melvoin | 101 Main ST | (525) 555-1911 | wendy@example.com
>
> Customer: 5851c90a-f1cb-4706-a329-c54890e4d190 | Lisa | Coleman | 787 Dream ST | (525) 555-7824 | lisa@example.com

Comment: Is there such a thing as going too far? +1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :-) Actually, this code is recycled from similar Answers of mine, just cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem even though all syntax was correct, I simply lacked the `commit()` statement

```
getConnection().commit();
```